# Как удалить подстроку из строки методом erase? c++

Tags: c++, строки, char

Для заполнения стека нужно ввести "push **какое-то число**"". Я записываю это в строку, затем пытаюсь удалить из нее подстроку начиная с 0-ого символа по 4-ый символ, чтобы строка содержала только число, которое я позже преобразую к int и благополучно запихаю в стек. Что я делаю не так? Пробовал также str = str.erase (0,3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string str = "";
    cin >> str;
    str.erase(0, 4);
    cout << str;
```

Comment: проверил код, все удаляется. ну разве что заменил 4 на 5

Comment: прикольно. человек ведь описал желаемое поведение и минимальный код (ну почти рабочий). Но нет, проще закрыть вопрос.

Comment: вопрос сам закрылся, на этом сайте пока новенький

Comment: вопрос закрылся, потому что 5 человек решило, что он "плохо оформлен". Хотя я с ними не согласен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему не работает код. да все просто - `cin >> str;` вводит до первого пробела, потому что str - строка. Вот и все. Меняем немного

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string str;
    int n;
    cin >> str >> n;
    cout << "строка " << str << " число " << n;

}
```

и все работает. Если же хочется всю строку, что бы сохранить оригинальную идею - std::getline.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
str.erase(0, 5);
cout << str;
```